# Cant connect to Postgres running Strapi using Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, strapi

Im trying to run Strapi using but the connection to my Postgres DB always fails (The DB is hosted on Scaleway).I tried locating the error by running Strapi locally using `strapi start`, which works fine. Connecting with `psql -h xx.xxx.xxx.xx -p xxxxx -U strapi -d strapi`works locally and on my Compute Instance. So the connection itself cant be the problem and strapi also cant be. This is my Dockerfile:

```
# Creating multi-stage build for production
FROM node:18-alpine as build
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache build-base gcc autoconf automake zlib-dev libpng-dev vips-dev git > /dev/null 2>&1
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /opt/
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install -g node-gyp
RUN npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 600000 -g && npm install --only=production
ENV PATH /opt/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY . .
RUN npm run build # strapi build

# Creating final production image
FROM node:18-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache vips-dev
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
WORKDIR /opt/
COPY --from=build /opt/node_modules ./node_modules
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY --from=build /opt/app ./
ENV PATH /opt/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

RUN chown -R node:node /opt/app
USER node
EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"] # strapi start
```

Im running the container with `sudo docker run -p 1337:1337 -p 22092:22092 --env-file .env rg.fr-par.scw.cloud/xxx/xxx`

I also made sure, that docker had access to all needed environment variables by printing them out when running the container, which worked.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. My password was using some special characters, so i had to use quotes in my .env file. I changed that and tried the new one without quotes which worked :)